# Sharepoint SPWeb - MasterUrl vs CustomMasterUrl

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is the difference between the MasterUrl and CustomMasterUrl in SPWeb please?

Comment: you might want to ask this on sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best description comes from Site Settings > Look and Feel > Master Page in the SharePoint UI.

This is [SPWeb.CustomMasterUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.custommasterurl.aspx):

> **Site Master Page**
>
> The site master page will be used by all publishing pages.

This is [SPWeb.MasterUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.masterurl.aspx):

> **System Master Page**
>
> Use the system master page for all forms and view pages in this site.

Comment: Knew this already, but +1 for clear and concise answer.